# Initialise an object with array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, initialization

How can I initialise an object in JavaScript, the properties of which would be arrays?

I want to have an object of this format:

```
foo = { prop1: [0, 1], prop2: [1, 1], prop3: [0] }
```

My usecase is the following:

*- When a property does not exist, create this property which should be an array and add a number.*

*- When a property exists already, push the number to that array; this way I cannot initialise an array every time.*

What I've done so far is this:

```
  var obj = {};
  arr.forEach(x => { !obj[x] && obj[x].push(1) });
```

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

which makes sense, as the property has not been initialised as an empty array.

Comment: can you give us some examples for input and desired output?

Comment: For example, I am iterating over two arrays, I want to have 0/1 (or true/false) if the arrays include some specific items, e.g. array1 = ["cat", "dog"], array2 = ["dog", "mouse"]; the object would be of this format: { "cat": [1, 0], "dog": [1, 1], "mouse": [0,1] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this snippet:

```
arr.forEach((x) => {obj[x] = (obj[x] || []).concat(1);})
```

If `obj[x]` is `undefined`, then it hasn't been initialized. Therefore, `undefined || []` resolves to `[]`, an empty array, to which `1`, or whatever data you want, can be concatenated.

Comment: This is elegant :)

Comment: Thanks! Javascript's lazy `||` operator can be very useful. It's often used in functions with optional parameters, to replace `undefined` with a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao you could try this:

```js
let obj = {};
let arr = ["prop1","prop2","prop1","prop3"];
arr.forEach((x) => {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) obj[x].push(1);
   else {
      obj[x] = [];
      obj[x].push(1);
   } 
})
console.log(obj);
```

if obj has already property x (`hasOwnProperty`) push value 1 else init x as array property and push 1.

Comment: Thank you, this is also a nice solution!